# Running Firebase Push notifications in Laravel Vue

Tags: laravel, firebase, vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to configure push notifications for my Laravel/Vue app.

I have installed the firebase package into my node_modules, including firebase/messaging.

Here is how I have imported the files.

```
var firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/messaging');

var fireConfig = {} //Config 


const messaging = firebase.messaging();

export default {
  messaging
}
```

However, doing this gives the error `firebase.messaging()` is not a function.

How do I go about this, since many tutorials (at least, the ones I have seen so far) seem to be able to get through this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `firebase.initializeApp()` before calling `firebase.messaging()` (or any Firebase product accessor).

Notice that [step 3](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize) of the instructions has you initialize Firebase first:

```
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

// Add the Firebase products that you want to use
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
```

Followed by init:

```
// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

It's not until later until [step 5](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#namespace) that you access Firebase in your app:

```
firebase.messaging()
```

The call to `firebase.messaging()` must come after init in your code.

Comment: Oh, I had omitted that line in writing this question. Sorry for that.